# Include library without project

Tags: c++, hyperlink, header, project, static-libraries

I have created a library with some functions and now I'd like to use it whitout creating a code blocks or a dev c++ project, but it seems it doens't function in this mode. I want have only main.cpp, lib.h e lib.cpp files and be able to compile main.cpp including library correctly, but now it gives me the error *undefined reference to* for every function called that is in the library.
Is it possibile, and how? Thank you

Comment: How are you building your project? using command line? Which compiler?

Comment: How would you create a program, that tests your library, without using CodeBlocks?  What other IDE would you like to use?  Or do you want to link the program via command line?

Answer (score 0):

Why you won´t just make a project? That´s the reason projects exist in the first place.
You could do the linker call yourself, but what´s the point if your IDE could do it for you?

edit:
Possibilities
a) Make project files for each popular IDE
b) Make one (or more) makefile for some makefile-execution program
c) Just transfer the code and make the stuff when you need it, for the local environment.

There is no universal project file which is readble by all programs.

Comment: Beacuse I would like that this files can be opened from someone who don't have necessary my IDE, for example I use code blocks and I would like that someone who uses Dev can also open my file, but I think dev can't open code blocks projects.

Comment: @Vitto Someone who doesn't have your IDE will need to tell their IDE how to build the project. The knowledge of how to build the project has to be encoded somehow in order for the project to be built. If you don't have any tool in common, then each of you will have to do this in a way your own tool understands.

Comment: You have to create an appropriate project file for whatever tool you want to use to build the project. The knowledge of how to build the project must be encoded somehow in order for the project to be built. Each tool has its own way to represent that knowledge. If you want to use tool X, then you have to put that knowledge in a form tool X understands.

Comment: Ok, I understand that I can only create a project with one IDE and other people rebuild it with their IDE if it's different. And if I used command line I immagine it would be the the same, people should rebuild the project with their IDE to compile it, right?

Comment: IDEs are not required to build a project.  One can use a *makefile* and GNU compilers or using Visual Studio's command line version.  If you want to give your project to another person, give them the files and tell them about any dependencies.

Comment: If you enter the compiler options etc. directly in a shell, they are only the same if you use the same compiler (probably same version needed), same linker, same OS (if you want more than just compiling/linking, like copying some files around) and so on. So yes, the best option is to provide project files for one or some few popular tools. If someone want to use others, he should make his own one´s.

Comment: Ok. A friend suggested me to insert the definition of the function directly in the header file of the library, but I don't think it's a good solution.
Is there any model to follow to write the documentation about how include the libraries when someone compile my code?